# Rails routing: still a bit confused on how to pass a query param through different requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

On a search page I submit a query to the index action via a form:

```
= form_tag reports_path, method: 'get' do
  = text_field_tag :query, params[:query]
```

I successfully pass it from `reports#index` view into `#show` view with:

```
= link_to params[:query] ? query_report_path(report.id, params[:query]) : report do
```

which is possible because of this route:

```
  resources :reports do
    get ':query', to: 'reports#show', on: :member, as: :query
```

but I'm trying to get same query back to #index action from a `link` in the `reports#show` view with:

```
= link_to 'Back', reports_path, query: @query
```

but it's failing: `:query` = *nil*.

also tried:

```
= link_to 'Back', reports_path(query: @query, class: 'btn btn-small')
```

which doesnt' work at all...

routing syntax has me tripped up...again! What's the correct syntax? Is there a better way to do this? Why wouldn't this trigger the same **get** `reports#index` with `:query` param that the initial `form_tag` is triggering?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you set a @query instance variable?

Comment: yes, i've tried it with `query: params[:query]` and most recently `query: @query` by setting (and confirming @query is being set) `@query = params[:query]` in the controller.

Comment: my suspicion is that there's something wrong with syntax of `= link_to 'Back', reports_path, query: params[:query]` but I can't figure out what it is!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second try is close but your parentheses are wrong.  Try passing the HTML options hash `class: 'btn btn-small'` as the third argument to `link_to` instead of as an argument to `reports_path`.

Comment: you da man!! here's what worked... `= link_to 'Back', reports_path(query: @query), class: 'btn btn-small'
`

Comment: Aside: the "optional parenthesis" in Rails makes the framework *harder* to learn/understand, actually, IMHO...